Generar PDF de una jtable con rango de fechas
tengo una consulta que me trae de cabeza hace un par de semanas. Estoy haciendo una aplicacion con java y mysql. En una clase llamada cargasMensuales genero un jTable con las cargas que han salido del almacen segun un rango de fechas a elegir en la misma ventana. Y esa tabla con los resultados quiero que al clicar sobre el button "generar pdf" me genere un reporte en pdf. Alguna orientación? He visto generar los pdf con datos de tablas pero no cuando se le da un rango de fechas o parametros. Gracias de antemano y perdon por el tocho.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! "He visto generar los pdf con datos de tablas" y cual seria la diferencia? una tabla filtrada es una tabla ;)

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
